# Remove spaces above and below cmidrule

Tags: spacing, rules, booktabs

I'm using `booktabs` to create table and use `cmidrule` to span a line across a few columns. The problem is when the cells have background color, the spaces around `cmidrule` makes it look really bad.

While, `booktabs` allow you to trim the left and right side of `cmidrule`, I don't see the options for setting spaces above and below it to 0.

This is the code I have:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}    
\bfrule       % this is specialrule with no spaces above and below
\rowcolor[gray]{.8}
\multirow{2}{*}{}           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Big group}} \\
                    %\cline{2-3}
                    \cmidrule(){2-3}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8}         &  subgroup1 &  subgroup2 \\
\hline
Item 1      & 10 & 50\\
Item 2          &  5 & 25 \\
\bfrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and this is what I got.
[image]

Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks,

**Update**

As David pointed out in his comment, removing spaces won't solve the problem. There's still thin line of white color at the left and/or right of the midline.

[image]

Comment: even if you reduce the space to 0pt so the colour touches the rules, you will still have a white line at either end of the cline, are you sure you want to mix the formal style of booktabs with the more casual style of colortbl?

Comment: you're probably right. I'm not familiar with `colortbl`. I'm just trying to work around `booktabs` as I've already had a few tables using it. My ultimate goal is to have the a line spanning a few columns without breaking the cell background color.

Comment: `colortbl` is the package providing the background colour in your example (probably loaded via xcolor's table option)

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. yes, I used xcolor's table option to color the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with `hhline` and the `boldline` package produces a more acceptable result:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, float, booktabs, boldline, hhline}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \hlineB{2} % this is specialrule with no spaces above and below
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Big group}} \\
    %\cline{2-3}
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor [gray]{0.8}}->{\arrayrulecolor {black}}--}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8} & subgroup1 & subgroup2 \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
    Item 1 & 10 & 50 \\
    Item 2 & 5 & 25 \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]